# Connect WP8 to Zarafa/Synology mailserver only using mobile data when home WiFi not available

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, synology, windows-phone-8

I have a Lumia 1520 WP8 phone that I'm trying to connect to my Zarafa mail server on a Synology rackstation.  The rackstation is connected to the internet via a DLink DSL-2890AL router which connects to the internet via ADSL.  The synology device and the router have static 192.168... IP addresses which are required for other functions that they must perform.

Currently, the Lumia 1520 connects to the Zarafa mail server through the internet using the router's DDNS address.  However, it does this even when at home and wifi is available, using the mobile data allowance rather than wifi and the ADSL data allowance, which is much greater and faster.

Is there any way to specify to the Lumia 1520 that it should connect to the Zarafa mail server via WiFi if it is available using its local 192.168...  address rather than going via the mobile network using the DDNS address?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Router has NAT loopback, or sometimes referred to as hairpin NAT. Then just make sure you turn off the cellular data when you are at home. You can also use ITTT or some similar scripting utility to automate the "turn off cellular data" bit, based on your location.

Comment: I'm looking for something that *just works*.  Turning off cellular data currently doesn't work, and I don't want to have to remember to do it, and WP8.1 doesn't have such scripting capability.

Comment: So currently, if you turn off cellular data, checking mail via WIFI doesn't work? I'm inclined to think that the router doesn't have Nat Loopback then... check with D-Link first, but I would think that feature will help achieving what you are after.